# How to set height of a div to height of the screen dynamically till the scrollbar reach bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I am trying to have a vertical line for a news feed and i am looking for a solution to make its height equal to the screen when scrollbar reach bottom of the screen dynamically as items in the news feed will be loaded dynamically on scroll.

I tried using 100vh and 100% but then height is fixed to the height of the viewport.

Here is the div :

```
<div class="verticalLineFeed">
</div>
```

CSS for the div :

```
.verticalLineFeed {
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
border-left: 5px solid #cdcdcd;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 32px;
margin-top: 65px;
}
```

Any idea for doing this in css3 or jquery will be helpful

Code Snippet :

```css
.verticalLineFeed {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid #cdcdcd;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="verticalLineFeed">
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `min-height: 100vh`?

Comment: Yes, that did not work

Comment: Then you need to post a minimal code snippet reproducing the issue or else we will have no chance other than guessing

Comment: @LGSon Created...

Comment: removing `height: 2000px` from `.main` seems to work?

Comment: @1252748 removing .main will make line height to screen height, issue here is I need the height of the line to be equal to main div, I have got a way to do it, posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `wrapper` and set it to `position: relative`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.verticalLineFeed {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid #cdcdcd;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="verticalLineFeed">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or set `position: relative` to the `body` (haven't tested this on all browsers though)

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.verticalLineFeed {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid #cdcdcd;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="verticalLineFeed">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a way to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
  windowHeight = $('.main').innerHeight();
  $('.verticalLineFeed').css('height', windowHeight);
  };

  setHeight();

  $('.main').resize(function() {
  setHeight();
  });
});
```

Code Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $('.main').innerHeight();
    $('.verticalLineFeed').css('height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();
  
  $('.main').resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

```css
.verticalLineFeed {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid #cdcdcd;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="verticalLineFeed">
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I posted 2 samples, each much more efficient than using script, which I recommend you don't use when there is a CSS way of doing it